# a PHP file to post to my page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have a script to post updates to our website to our facebook page as well. I created an API for this, got all the app_id's and such and added my facebook profile as both admin on the facebook page and added a manager role on the APP as well.

I read it wasn't necessary to get the APP reviewed by FaceBook if you're not publishing the app anywhere. This is not a website other people can use to post content, it's merely an admin tool to let us post our updates on our facebook page.

I post run my test post with this code (ID's removed):

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook( [
  'app_id'                => APP_ID,    
  'app_secret'            => APP_SECRET,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  'default_access_token'  => DEFAULT_ACCESS_TOKEN
] );


$attachment = [
    'message' => 'this is a test message',
];

try{
    $result = $fb->post( '419661214806422/feed', $attachment );
} catch( Exception $e ){
    echo "<pre>" . print_r( $e, true ) . "</pre>";
}
```

This gives me an error message: `(#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission`. I don't know where to edit my permissions though. My account is the admin for the facebook page, and it has also been added as manager of the APP I'm writing. I tried searching on the web all afternoon, but I can only find information about APPs actually open to the public, which is something I don't need. I therefor can also not give a link to facebook for reviewing, since this is part of our admin.

Comment: authorize your app with publish_pages and manage_pages then, as it says in the error message. also, make sure to select YOUR app in the api explorer, not the api explorer app (the default).

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting your default access token from? You can debug your token here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken. It will tell you the permissions yuo have. During the auth flow, you would need to have granted those permissions to your app in order to post.

Comment: I got if from the facebook API explorer at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/, that will give an access token for the API I created

Comment: ok perfect. so when you are on that page, before copying the token infront of you, click the "Get Token" option on the right handside. Then click "Get User Access token. When you get a list of permissions you want to ask for, make sure you select Manage_Pages and Publish_Pages permissions. Then you will be prompted via auth flow to accept those permissions. After that, click the dropdown again, this time you will see a list of your pages you have access to. Select your one and you will be given that page access token in order to publish.

Comment: What I would then suggest is, after grabbing that token, visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken again and paste in your new token. It will give you info on it, but also will give you the ability to "Extend token" which will give you a new token that lasts much longer than the hour.

Comment: I got this feedback from Facebook: Your app doesn't need to submit for manage_pages or publish_pages to post to Pages or blogs that you admin. As an app admin, you can already access these permissions and post to your own timeline, pages and groups.
You can provide access to additional users by adding them to your app as admin or developers. Only apply for manage_pages or publish_pages if your app uses a public-facing login that third party users will access externally.

Comment: turned out you need the the AccessToken for the page, not the one for the app (found at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).